# Node JS - Compare IPv4 with IPv6

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ip, sails.js

I use express JS (Sails JS).

My goal is to allow only certain IP addresses for certain APIs. The "allowed" IPs are inserted in IPv4 representation.

The req.ip returns the current request's IP, however, the IP is in IPv6 representation.

There are couple of libraries that deal with conversions from IPv4 to IPv6. One of them is https://github.com/whitequark/ipaddr.js/

The way I do the comparison is by normalizing the 2 IPs and compare the normalized string. Obviously, for IPv4, I map it to IPv6 then normalize it.

```
// allowedIPs is the array of allowed IPs
var isAllowed = _.some(allowedIPs, function(ip) {
    return IPService.areEqualIPs(ip, userIP);
});
```

The IPService.js

```
var ipaddr = require('ipaddr.js');

exports.validateIP = function(ipStr) {
    return ipaddr.isValid(ipStr);
}

exports.getNormalizedIPv6String = function(ipStr) {
    if ( !ipaddr.isValid(ipStr) ) {
        var err = new Error('Invalid IP');
        throw err 
    }

    var ipObj = ipaddr.parse(ipStr);

    // Normalize IPv4 to IPv6 format
    if ( ipaddr.IPv4.isValid(ipStr) ) {
        return ipObj.toIPv4MappedAddress().toNormalizedString();
    }

    // Return normalized IPv6 format
    return ipObj.toNormalizedString();
}

exports.areEqualIPs = function(ip1, ip2) {
    return exports.getNormalizedIPv6String(ip1) === exports.getNormalizedIPv6String(ip2);
}
```

However, the normalization is not given the same results for the majority of the IPs

For example

```
ipaddr.parse("::1").toNormalizedString(); // 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
ipaddr.parse("127.0.0.1").toIPv4MappedAddress().toNormalizedString(); // 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:7f00:1
```

How can I compare IPv4 vs IPv6?

Comment: I don't honestly think you can.  You can't take any IPv6 address and make a canonical IPv4 address from it.  IPv6 is a much larger address space that covers a lot more space than IPv4.

Comment: I am not making IPv6=>IPv6 but vise-versa

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're trying to do.  There is not a one-to-one mapping between IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses.  A system may be allocated one of each for some purposes, but there isn't an auto way to map from one to the other in either direction.

Comment: that doesn't make sense. IPv4 must be represented in IPv6 and that what happens actually. IPv6 => IPv4 is impossible.

Comment: An IPv4 address can be represented in IPv6 format.  An IPv6 address can only be represented in IPv4 format if it happens to be from the IPv4 subset of IPv6.  If it's a full-blown IPv6 address, then there is no IPv4 representation of it as IPv6 is a much larger space of numbers than can fit in IPv4.  So, you could only match your IPv6 addresses to your IPv4 table if the IPv6 addresses happened to be from the more limited subset of IPv6 - but there's kind of no point in using IPv6 if it's going to be limited to the IPv4 subset.

Comment: well, my client will be entering IP to be banned and they want to enter it in IPv4, which is ok, as theoretically speaking, we can convert it to IPv6 and then do the comparison with the client IP (my server listens to IPv6). That's what I am trying to do, and the normalization of the IPs does NOT seem to work in my case.

Comment: Show the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses that you think are supposed to match.  Not much else we discuss on the theory because it all depends upon the IPv6 address and whether its a full-blown IPv6 address that has no IPv4 conversion or not.

Comment: Personally, I think you should tell your client that it's an IPv6 world now and that's what they should expect connecting clients to be using.  You can handle dumbing down to IPv4 if needed, but not the other way around.